# algorithm to convert array integers into RGB value (similar to excel)

Tags: ruby

Given an array of positive and negative integers...

I would like to return a green or red  gradient color relative to its value in the array.

Similar to excel conditional formatting, the greens should be darker the closer they are to the maximum. lighter if they're closer to the minimum.

**SIMILAR TO THIS IMAGE BELOW:**
[image: foo]

Currently i'm doing this

```
if value == Float::INFINITY
  "rgba(0,255,0,1)"
elsif value > 0
  "rgba(0,255,0, #{Rational(value, maximum).to_f.round(2)})"
else
  "rgba(255,0,0,#{Rational(value, minimum).to_f.abs.round(2)})"
end
```

Comment: This question only makes sense in the context of some sort of color object and you have specified none. The type used in Excel is specific that program and the GUI environment. Neither of these things exist in Ruby. You could of course create a Color class and populate it with RGB values, but they would be meaningless to the system environment. Now if you are using Ruby with a GUI framework, you could use the color type of that framework, but that too is not specified.

Comment: There are libraries out there than handle color gradients: https://github.com/zeeraw/gradient - use your array of table values to create points over a color gradient canvass and you should be good to go. unless there's a good reason to invest a lot of time coming up with your own unique solution, i'd suggest leverage existing solutions to speed up the finish.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an array of floats (or strings or `BigDecimal`s converted to floats):

```
arr = [
  [25.1, 13.5, 4.3],
  [28.3, 11.6, 5.9],
  [16.5, 17.3, 6.4]
]
```

It's of course arbitrary how these numbers are to be converted to shades of red and green, but here is one possibility. Suppose we compute:

```
mn, mx = arr.flatten.minmax
  #=> [4.3, 28.3] 
av = (mn+mx).fdiv(2)
  #=> 16.3
```

Then the red hues could decrease linearly from 255 at 28.3 to 0 at 16.3 and the green hues could increase linearly from 0 at 16.3 to 255 at 4.3:

```
def rg_gradient(arr)
  mn, mx = arr.flatten.minmax
  av = (mn+mx).fdiv(2)
  above = mx-av
  below = av-mn
  arr.map do |a|
    a.map { |n| n > av ? [(255*(n-av)/above).round, 0] :
      [0, (255*(1-(av-n)/below)).round] }
  end
end
```

```
rg_gradient(arr)
  #=> [[[187, 0], [ 0, 195], [0,  0]],
  #    [[255, 0], [ 0, 155], [0, 34]],
  #    [[  4, 0], [21,   0], [0, 45]]]
```